# How to get dhtmlxcalendar to fire events on single click

Tags: javascript, calendar, dom-events

By default `dhtmlxcalendar` fires events on double click. This is unnatural for web users. How do you change all events to fire on single click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply reassigning the `_on_mouse_down` function to `_on_dbl_click` seems to do the trick:

```
scheduler._on_mouse_down = scheduler._on_dbl_click;
```